# How to manage full screen in IE via automation? (Flash player like)

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, fullscreen

I'm facing a problem with IE7 full screen mode.

Got an app lying in an activeX embedded in IE. Until IE6, we managed fullscreen via

> IWebBrowser2::put_FullScreen(bool bIsFull)
>   which was good and well.

But since IE7, it seems that this trick is deprecated, as it looses the tab bar on the way back from fullscreen.

One solution would be to go with the call to

> IWebBrowser2::put_TheaterMode(bool bIsFull)
>   which seems to be what's done in IE7 when stroking F11

But that's not what I want, since there's the tab and address bar in auto hide mode

So I'd like to achieve a true fullscreen mode, like what's done in flash for fullscreen youtube videos.

Do you know any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Flash doesn't use the browser to enter full screen, it does it by invoking native OS libraries.

Comment: oh? interesting. Could you please give me some inputs on those libraries?

Comment: I think flash uses DirectX on a windows platform, but not to sure about other platforms (probably OpenGL).