# How to log a bug on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, bug-tracking

I found a clear squared bug on IE7/8, which appears via automation ([still looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246365/how-to-manage-full-screen-in-ie-via-automation-flash-player-like) for a workaround, btw).

So, I tried with no luck to find a way to log this bug. Tried the [forum way](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.internetexplorer.general/browse_thread/thread/0f8439d0751578a6#), but it seems this site is somehow not so active these days.

I even tried to mail [Chris Wilson](http://cwilso.com/), but honestly, I don't put so much hope in this attempt ;o)

So, do anyone know a way to log a bug on IE?

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: you sure its a bug? ;) Could be a 'feature'... M$ has a ton of those...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/07/30/wanted-ie8-beta-testers.aspx:

> Currently the only way to directly
>   file a bug with the IE Team is to be a
>   part of the IE8 Technical Beta program
>   on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com).

However, that post also said:

> If you wish to be a part of making IE
>   better by contributing great bug
>   reports then please email us at
>   IESO@microsoft.com and tell us a
>   little about yourself including why
>   you’d be a great beta tester.

Maybe emailing Chris Wilson was a good idea!

Comment: Tried the mail to IESO, maybe I'll be granted a beta tester hat (not that I want one, but I definitively want this bug registered, as I've got an upset customer for this very reason). Kudos you've got the point.

Answer (score 2):

I think people running these bug lists are listening:

http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/search/label/IE7

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=InternetExplorerWinBugs

http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html

http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/

Comment: Well, submited in webbugtrack, as it's not CSS centered.
Thanks, we'll see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

As Phil said, using the IE Feedback system is your best bet, although results vary from "yeah thanks for the report" to "sorry maybe in the next release" ;-)

Can you elaborate on the bug or provide some code?  We may have an answer if we know the exact issue.  I'd also be happy to submit the bug for you in connect if I have enough details to reproduce it.

Comment: silly me, I just read the linked article(s)... hmm, I don't play with ActiveX at all so I'm sorry I don't have any answers.

Comment: I'd be glad if you submited this bug in connect, just pick the code from microsoft newsgroup and compile it in VC, you'll have the POC